# AAR Modules not uploaded in the maven repository

Tags: android, maven, gradle, aar

I'm trying to convert an existing app to an AAR.

I managed to turn it into an AAR, autogenerate the pom file and upload it in a maven repository.
The generated pom file correctly include the relative dependencies, like for example:

```
implementation "joda-time:joda-time:2.10.1"
```

get converted in:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
    <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
    <version>2.10.1</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

My problem is that the app also use local libraries/modules, like this:

```
implementation project(':CameraModule')
implementation project(':VideoTranscoderModule')
```

when the pom file is generated this libraries are included in it with the following format:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>myapp-android</groupId>
    <artifactId>CameraModule</artifactId>
    <version>unspecified</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>myapp-android</groupId>
    <artifactId>VideoTranscoderModule</artifactId>
    <version>unspecified</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

this dependencies are not resolved when trying to include the AAR in another app

```
implementation ('com.myapp.sdk:thesdk:1.1.2') {
    transitive = true
}
```

And I ger the following build error:

```
   > Could not find myapp-android:CameraModule:unspecified.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/myapp-android/CameraModule/unspecified/CameraModule-unspecified.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/myapp-android/CameraModule/unspecified/CameraModule-unspecified.pom
       - http://localhost:8081/repository/maven-releases/myapp-android/CameraModule/unspecified/CameraModule-unspecified.pom
```

How can I solve this?

This is my publishing gradle script:

```
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
apply plugin: 'signing'

tasks.register("sourceJar", Jar) {
    from android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
    archiveClassifier.set('sources')
}

project.ext["signing.keyId"] = "ABCDE123" 
project.ext["signing.secretKeyRingFile"] = "aar-signing.key" 
project.ext["signing.password"] = "ThePasswordHere123"

afterEvaluate {
    publishing {
        publications {
            releaseAar(MavenPublication) {
                from components.debug
                artifact sourceJar

                groupId = "com.myapp.sdk"
                artifactId = "thesdk"
                version = "1.1.2"

                pom {
                    name = 'My App SDK'
                    description = 'Testing'
                    url = 'https://example.com/'

                    licenses {
                        license {
                            name = 'The Apache License, Version 2.0'
                            url = "http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt"
                        }
                    }

                    developers {
                        developer {
                            id = 'Something'
                            name = 'Myname Here'
                            email = 'email@example.com'
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        repositories {
            maven {
                name = "mynexusrepo"
                credentials {
                    username = "username123"
                    password = "123password"
                }
                url = uri("http://localhost:8081/repository/maven-releases/")
                allowInsecureProtocol = true
            }
        }
    }

    signing {
        sign(publishing.publications)
    }
}
```

Comment: If your SDK uses local libraries or dependencies that not listed in pom file, you have to add them manually to app gradle.